# Why can a naive abs implementation not be optimized well in C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, floating-point, compiler-optimization, ieee-754

I was looking at how a naive implementation of `abs(float)` would compile and was quite surprised by the result:

```cpp
float abs(float x) {
    return x < 0 ? -x : x;
}
```

With clang 10.1 at -O3, this results in:

```
.LCPI0_0:
        .long   2147483648              # float -0
        .long   2147483648              # float -0
        .long   2147483648              # float -0
        .long   2147483648              # float -0
abs(float):
        movaps  xmm2, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0]
        xorps   xmm2, xmm0
        xorps   xmm3, xmm3
        movaps  xmm1, xmm0
        cmpltss xmm1, xmm3
        andps   xmm2, xmm1
        andnps  xmm1, xmm0
        orps    xmm1, xmm2
        movaps  xmm0, xmm1
        ret
```

I find that quite surprising, because I honestly just expected the sign bit of the float to be cleared, which should just be a single XOR instruction. There's got to be something about IEEE-754 floating point semantics that causes this complication, but I just don't understand what makes it **this** complicated. Why would you need any more than a compare and a conditional move?

Maybe it's because the comparison with NaN would always fail, so the sign bit doesn't get cleared in such a case? But since the sign bit can be 0 or 1 for NaN, that shouldn't matter.

For comparison, when simply using `std::fabs` the output is much simpler which is exactly what one would expect:

```cpp
abs(float):
        andps   xmm0, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0]
        ret
```

The same output is produced when enabling the `-ffast-math` flag.

**Update:** gcc 10.2 at -O3 produces:

```
abs(float):
        pxor    xmm1, xmm1
        comiss  xmm1, xmm0
        ja      .L6
        ret
.L6:
        xorps   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        ret
```

Comment: Consider what should happen for +0, -0 and various NaN.

Comment: For what it's worth, icc seems to be doing a way better job.

Comment: gcc generates simpler code with a jump, while clang prefers branchless code, which requires setting things up.

Comment: @SergeyA icc uses its equivalent of -ffast-math by default, IIRC, so the comparison isn't fair.

Comment: Unless you tell the compiler otherwise, NaN values have a meaning, it isn't allowed to replace one NaN with another one. But the case of -0. may be easier to understand.

Comment: @MarcGlisse that's right, with precise model code seems to be in-line with other compiler.

Comment: "The same output is produced when enabling the -ffast-math flag". That should ring a pretty loud bell.

Comment: An interesting related case is max: SSE has an instruction maxss which corresponds to what people naively write with ?: and cannot be used for fmaxf.

Comment: `-ffast-math` breaks language rules.

Comment: FWIW `__builtin_assume(x == x)` did not work... that should let the compiler know it isn't dealing with NaN (but may still have infinities or denormals)

Comment: OP's `abs(-0.0f)` results in `-0.0f`.  For an absolute value function, I'd exptect `0.0f`.  `return signbit(x) ? -x : x;` makes more sense or `return copysign(x, 0.0f);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IEEE floating point space contains a number of special values, such as both positive and negative 0, positive and negative infinities, and two families of "Not a Number" (NaN).  All of these values have well-defined semantics wrt. the `<` operator, and so the compiler must generate code that deals correctly with all the special cases.

The flag `-ffast-math` can be used to inform the compiler that it may assume that the special values are not being used, that the distinction between positive and negative 0 is irrelevant and to make some other simplifying assumptions (such as that addition is associative).  With this flag, clang generates what is probably optimal code for your `abs` function:

```
abs:
        andps   .LCPI0_0(%rip), %xmm0
        retq
```

The choice of respecting the somewhat baroque IEEE semantics by default is somewhat controversial; compilers other than gcc and clang tend to make the opposite choice, they compile fast and compact code by default, and require an explicit command-line flag if full IEEE compliance is required (e.g. `-mp` in the case of the Intel compiler).